# two-level cache (memory + redis) implementation in Go

Tags: go, caching, concurrency, mutex

I am trying to write a two-level cache (memory + redis), but I got a bottleneck when there is a high concurrency access for one key, I tried to use mutex for each key, but this increased cpu a lot since loadFromDB takes 100-200ms.

```
func (s *Store) GetJsonObjectWithExpire(key string, obj interface{}, ttl int, f StoreLoadFunc) error {
    // first read from memory
    v, ok := s.mem.Get(key)
    if ok {
        if v.Outdated() {
            to := deepcopy.Copy(obj)
            go s.updateMem(key, to, ttl, f)
        }
        return nil
    }

    // if missed in memory, check from redis
    v, ok = s.rds.Get(key, obj)
    if ok {
        if v.Outdated() {
            go s.rds.loadFromDB(key, nil, ttl, f, false)
        }
        return nil
    }
    return s.rds.loadFromDB(key, obj, ttl, f, true)
}
```

loadFromDB will load object from db and write it to redis and memory, this will take about 100-200ms, both loadFromDB and rds.Get function use per-key RWMutex right now.

since there will be a lot of keys(10000+),I am not sure if it is a good idea to use a mutex for each key?

Is there any thing that I can do to improve the performance?

UPDATE:
Here is my code on github for my two-level cache-aside pattern implementation.

https://github.com/seaguest/cache

Comment: Having many mutexes does not consure CPU resources. How you use them may do so. We know little about your actual code, so it's hard to help you out.

Comment: If I understand the task correct, the number of mutexes (hm... mutices?) depends on the number of resources being accessed, not on the number of users. That all said, need an MCVE to tell more.

Comment: "need a mutex per each user" it's hard to imagine such a use case, can you elaborate?

Comment: If I understand, you're doing some calculation that takes a long time, and you don't want to do it more than once, if you receive simultaneous requests. What should happen if two equal requests come in together? Do both need to wait for the calculation to complete, or is it okay if one (or even both) get old data?

Comment: @Flimzyyes, exactly

Comment: So... What should happen if two equal requests come in together? Do both need to wait for the calculation to complete, or is it okay if one (or even both) get old data?

Comment: @icza I did a stress test at 500 routines, the mutex increases cpu a lot at a high concurrency

Comment: @Flimzy once the first completed calculation, I will write it into memory cache, so the other will read from memory cache instead of redis.

Comment: Okay, but you didn't answer my question. Do both requests need to wait for the calculation, or can one or both return old data instead?

Comment: @Flimzyyes, both need to return. otherwise the user side will get wrong data.

Comment: Yes, you still didn't answer my question. Obviously you need to return something. :) Do they _need to wait for the calculation_, or can they receive old data?

Comment: @NestorSokil I updated my question, please check it again.

Comment: If it's okay to send old data, your simplest sync option is no mutex, but just a semaphore. When a request comes in, check if an update is in progress, and if not, start one in the background, then immediately return the (outdated) data.  For many applications, this is perfectly acceptable, and solves the contention problem nicely _and_ decreases response time, since nothing ever waits.

Comment: @Flimzy   if data is outdated, all requests need to wait the fresh data ready. either read from memory or read from redis.

Comment: @Flimzy thanks for your suggestion, but if there is no old data, this will be a problem, right? so some requests may not have data returned.

Comment: Depends on your situation, but yes, that likely makes it problematic.

Comment: I imagine what you would need is a loading cache? That will take a loading function and handle the concurrency issues internally. A quick google search led me to https://github.com/bluele/gcache

Comment: @pandaadb  I am trying to write a two level cache(memory +redis) with a load func, I am starting with https://github.com/patrickmn/go-cache, the gcache seems not lightweight enough.

Comment: I think your problem is that GoRoutines block too much under high concurrent pressure (Assume N * 10000 goroutine what get 10000 user data). If so, it's better solve this instead of 'find elegant solution for mutexes'. Because mutexes do not bother you if you don't use them.

Comment: Is this question a continuation of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55768699/golang-redis-concurrency-scheduler-performance-issue ?

Comment: @marco.m, not exactly, I was testing a redis-based rate limiter then. but the problem seems the same, redis operation (db access + redis write/read) takes some time (100-200 ms) which causes the problem at high concurrency access.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, here is my github repo:

[A lightweight distributed two-level cache (memory + redis) with loader function library for Go.](https://github.com/seaguest/cache)

Welcome to have a try, any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach `go-cache` from https://github.com/viney-shih/go-cache .

A flexible multi-layered caching library interacts with **private (in-memory) cache** and **shared cache** (i.e. Redis) in Go. It provides `Cache-Aside` strategy when dealing with both. But more advanced, it maintains the consistency of private cache between distributed systems by `Pub-Sub` pattern.