# Redigo very slow on get (40ms)

Tags: go, redis

Simple `get` request to Redis through Golang Redigo takes ~ 40ms. At the same time executing
 the same `get` request through `redis-cli` takes ~ 0.040 ms. So how can I improve the performance?

I tried commenting `defer connection close()` and changing MaxIdle and MaxActive settings of Redigo without any success.

1) My Redigo code

```
package redis

import (
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
    "time"
    "app/utils/debug"

    "github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis"
)

var (
    Pool *redis.Pool
)

func init() {
    Pool = newPool(os.Getenv("REDIS_HOST"), os.Getenv("REDIS_PASSWORD"))
    cleanupHook()
}

func newPool(server string, password string) *redis.Pool {

    return &redis.Pool{

        MaxIdle:     100,
        MaxActive:   200,
        IdleTimeout: 240 * time.Second,

        Dial: func() (redis.Conn, error) {
            c, err := redis.Dial("tcp", server)
            if err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }
            if password != "" {
                if _, err := c.Do("AUTH", password); err != nil {
                    c.Close()
                    return nil, err
                }
            }
            return c, err
        },

        TestOnBorrow: func(c redis.Conn, t time.Time) error {
            _, err := c.Do("PING")
            return err
        },
    }
}

func cleanupHook() {
    c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt)
    signal.Notify(c, syscall.SIGTERM)
    signal.Notify(c, syscall.SIGKILL)
    go func() {
        <-c
        Pool.Close()
        os.Exit(0)
    }()
}


// Get - gets redis key
func Get(key string) ([]byte, error) {
    defer debug.TimeExecutionMeasure(time.Now())
    fmt.Println("GET1", key, time.Now())
    conn := Pool.Get()
    fmt.Println("GET2", key, time.Now())
    // defer conn.Close()

    fmt.Println("GET3", key, time.Now())
    var data []byte
    res1, res2 := conn.Do("GET", key)
    fmt.Println("GET4", key, time.Now())
    data, err := redis.Bytes(res1, res2)
    if err != nil {
        return data, fmt.Errorf("error getting key %s: %v", key, err)
    }
    fmt.Println("GET5", key, time.Now())
    return data, err
}
```

So the ~20ms takes `Pool.Get()` and another ~20ms takes `conn.Do("GET", key)`.

2) redis-cli ~0.04ms:

`MULTI` -> `TIME` -> `GET key` -> `TIME` -> `EXEC`

I get that this comparison with `redis-cli` is not correct, because we don't account time to establishing connection in `redis-cli`. But at least the `Get` operation itself should be fast. Why it takes 20ms ?

Any tips how to make pool reusable and improve get time?

UPDATE #1

If I simply run

```
func main() {
    _, _ = Get(key)
}
```

the time goes down to 6ms. But if `Get` is called inside my web application - it is still 40ms

UPDATE #2

```
package debug

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

// TimeExecutionMeasure - measures the time of function execution
func TimeExecutionMeasure(start time.Time) {
    elapsed := time.Since(start)

    // Skip this function, and fetch the PC and file for its parent.
    pc, _, _, _ := runtime.Caller(1)

    // Retrieve a function object this functions parent.
    funcObj := runtime.FuncForPC(pc)

    // Regex to extract just the function name (and not the module path).
    runtimeFunc := regexp.MustCompile(`^.*\.(.*)$`)
    name := runtimeFunc.ReplaceAllString(funcObj.Name(), "$1")

    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%s took %s", name, elapsed))
}
```

UPDATE #3

Tried to use go-redis. And `Get` time is ~1ms. Seems like for now I will use it

```
package redis

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"

    // "github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis"
    "app/utils/debug"

    "github.com/go-redis/redis/v7"
)

var (
    // Pool - redis pool
    Pool *redis.Client
)

func init() {
    Pool = redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr:     os.Getenv("REDIS_HOST"),
        Password: os.Getenv("REDIS_PASSWORD"), // no password set
        DB:       0,                           // use default DB
    })

}

// Get - get redis key
func Get(key string) ([]byte, error) {
    defer debug.TimeExecutionMeasure(time.Now())
    val, err := Pool.Get(key).Bytes()
    fmt.Println("Get error", err)
    return val, err
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you measure the time ?

Comment: (1) Because `defer conn.Close()` is commented out, the program leaks connections and will dial on repeated calls to `Get`.  Uncomment the code. (2) The program is configured to execute a `PING` command every time a connection is fetched from the pool. Remote TestOnBorrow.

Comment: @mgagnon I added the function, that measures execution of whole function

Comment: @CeriseLimón thanks for reply. I uncommented `defer conn.Close()` and removed `TestOnBorrow` - but seems like it didn't change anything.

Comment: Update I tried go-redis and it's much faster, like 1ms..

Comment: The changes should make a difference unless you are measuring the first use of the pool.   Measure the second use of the pool or prime the pool with a PING command before starting the measurement.  The go-redis and redigo packages do approximately the same work when executing a GET command on the network connection.  A large difference in time between the packages is likely a measurement error.  Show how `Get` is called.

Comment: Yes, the first run is x2 slower than latter. But it's still relatively large.

Comment: I have a web app with endpoints. I have one big function for each endpoint with a 4 gorutines functions, in each of them `Get` is called. Seems like it may be the case.

Comment: The big function is like `var wg sync.WaitGroup
 wg.Add(4)

 go func() {
  defer wg.Done()
  getFlightData(ctx, search, db)
 }()
 go func() {
  defer wg.Done()
  getCalendarAsync(ctx, search, calendarC)
 }()
 go func() {
  defer wg.Done()
  getBestDealsAsync(ctx, search, bestDealsC)
 }()
 go func() {
  defer wg.Done()
  getCurrentPriceAsync(search, db)
 }()
 wg.Wait()`

Comment: And each function `getFlightData`, `getCalendarAsync`, .. is calling redis.Get(key). Sometimes multiple times

Comment: According to this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55768699/golang-redis-concurrency-scheduler-performance-issue  `when the routine number increases, the execution time per routine per take function increases nearly exponentially.`

Comment: Uncommenting `defer conn.Close()` and removing `TestOnBorrow` should make a measurable difference in the times. Are you sure that you are using the version of the application with those changes?  It's time to run the profiler to find out what's wrong.